# Qt4.8 The effect of setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy ::Expanding , QSizePolicy ::Expanding) When I using QGridLayout

Tags: layout, qt4

I want slice the main windows as like this
[image: slice the main windows to 10 sub-windows]

my layout code is follow:

```
QGridLayout *gLayout = new QGridLayout ();

viewWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: #333;" );
for ( i = 0; i < m_numOfVideoWidget; i++)
{
     QWidget *vWidget = new QWidget(viewWidget);
     vWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy ::Expanding , QSizePolicy ::Expanding );
     videoList.append( vWidget);
}
index = 0;
for ( j = 0; j < 4; j += 2)
{
       gLayout->addWidget( videoList[ index++], 0, j, 2, 2);
}
for ( i = 2; i < 4; i++)
      for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            gLayout-> addWidget( videoList[ index++], i, j);
viewWidget->setLayout(gLayout );
```

Unfortunately, the result far from the expectation:
[image: bad result]

But when I remove the bellow sentence:

```
vWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy ::Expanding , QSizePolicy ::Expanding );
```

The result is my expected.

Why the

```
setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy ::Expanding , QSizePolicy ::Expanding );
```

can affect the QGridLayout?

thanks~

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you do not set the sizePolicy of the vWidget, but rather, of the "this" widget. Is that by intention?

My guess is that the grid layout tries to effect a size policy which is the sum of the size policies of the contents, while setting the size policy of the "this" widget sort of interferes with this.

Comment: Thanks for attention. I update the source code, add "vWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy ::Expanding , QSizePolicy ::Expanding )"